# Apache log analytic's

Tags: apache, looking-for-a-script, server-side-scripting, filenames, apache-log-files

Been trying for a while to get this script fully working I think I'm nearly there.

Ok so I basically need the script to show 3 things, email address - Browser type -  Time logged in.

```
EMAILS='/home/user/emaillist.txt'
MAIL=$EMAILS
while read MAIL;
do
grep -f $EMAILS /var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log>>/home/user/test.txt
done < $EMAILS
```

I need some way of first using the todays date in here so it only searches the apache logs for that data. I was thinking about using the linux date  +"[%d/%b/%Y" command in the script as this will match the correct date formate.

The other aspect is that I only need the output to show the user's email address | Browser type and date from apache nothing else.

HELP please

UPDATE

Managed to play around with the script and got it to this stage where it works fine I just need to work out how to add browser data into the text file?

```
x=$(date +"%d/%b/%Y")
y=$(date +"%d%b%Y")
filename=emaillist.txt 
while read filename
do 
        if COUNT=$(grep $filename /var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log |grep -c $x) 
        then  
        echo $filename:$COUNT>>/home/user/logs/usage"$y".txt  
        fi
done < emaillist.txt
```

Comment: Did the other script I wrote for you work?

Comment: @paulmorriss It I've managed to get the above script working as well now but just can't get the browser data into the script

Comment: @paulmorriss yep I accept that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put

```
grep $filename /var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log |grep $x | awk -F\" '{print $6}' | sort -u >> /home/user/logs/usage"$y".txt
```

before the `fi` that should put the browser information into the text file (and remove duplicate lines where they are the same) after the line with the count on it.

Comment: @paulmorriss the changes just adds a blank line underneath the users email in the text file

Comment: Do you want to try each bit in turn so the first grep, then the first and second grep and see what comes out.

Comment: @paulmorriss just done the grep on its on and its a blank text file

Comment: Are the counts after the username and the colon working?

Comment: @paulmorriss using a new blank script so no counts just that grep

Comment: Are you sure the emails in emaillist.txt are in the access log file?

Comment: @paulmorriss in the emaillist these are appearing the log as part of the GET /www/page/user@example/com/page.html

Comment: Do you really mean example/com? or is it example.com?

Comment: @paulmorriss sorry multitasking badly here its example.com

Comment: I give up. $filename should contain the email address. grep $filename accesslog should find any email addresses in the access log. If none are coming out when you run that then I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: @paulmorriss thanks for your help, I think it might have something to do the -c for the count

Comment: @paulmorriss yes it works fine without the -c

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: @paulmorriss I have one last question why wouldn't the script produce the text file when running as cron? Is it something to do with the variable for filename?

Comment: The line filename=emaillist.txt needs a full path before emaillist.txt. Similarly on the last line too.

Comment: @paulmorriss thought is was that, cheers